# App compat version for min sdk 9

Tags: android-studio, sdk, android-appcompat

I have Android Studio version 2.3.3 and `sdk` tools version 25.2.5. When I build a new project with min `sdk` 9 it makes a mistakes and i have to use min `sdk` 14 for my project.
it has anyway to change it to 9 and also use appcompat?
my default `appcompat` version is `v7:26.+`
I also read other questions but my problem didn't solve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting with version 26.0.0 of the Support Libraries the `minSdk` has been bumped to 14 (Android 4.0, [see this link](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions.html#26-0-0-alpha1)). If you have to support platforms down to API-Level 9 you have to use version `25.4.0` which is last one that supported every api level from 7 onwards.

**Note:** There's really no reason to support such old devices, according to the latest numbers they only account for roughly 0.7% of all devices. ([link](https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html))

Comment: I wrote 25.4.0 and it makes a mistake again but i use 25.0.1 and it solved but when i want to install my app in emulator and my my phone it not install.

Comment: What's the error? Note that you may have to change the targetSdk/compileSdk as well.

Comment: Just "App not installed". i used api 25 for targetSdk and CompileSdk. my previous projects were exatly like this one. when i install the new version of the android studio it makes a mistake

Comment: My problem solved. for generate apk i used v2(full apk signature) but this time i used v1(jar signature) and it installed without problem. Thanks to all.

Answer (score 0):

have to check the AppcombatActivity availabilty in Api. See this link https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatActivity.html