# How Can I Write Android Application with api 9 on Android-studio 3.4.1?

Tags: android, sdk

I Want to write an Android Application for Devices Running Android 2.3 and later. But It has some issues.

At first my "build.gradle" was:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "#.#.#"
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

But on build I get this error message:

```
ERROR: Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 9 cannot be smaller than version 14 declared in library [com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0] /home/#/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/2f2898e7868f192ee52215913109e968/AndroidManifest.xml as the library might be using APIs not available in 9
    Suggestion: use a compatible library with a minSdk of at most 9,
        or increase this project's minSdk version to at least 14,
        or use tools:overrideLibrary="android.support.v7.appcompat" to force usage (may lead to runtime failures)
```

I can't change 'targetSdkVersion' and 'compileSdkVersion' because this error will be occurred:

```
Google Play requires that apps target API level 26 or higher.
```

Can you please tell me what should I do?

Comment: As the error says that "'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'" cannot be used below 14 API. So you cannot use. And also official document says: Note: The minimum SDK version for all support library packages is at least API level 14. Some packages require a higher API level, as noted below.

https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/packages

Comment: I removed that library but yet it has error: ERROR: Failed to resolve: support-annotations

Comment: Yes, Because your project might be using it.

Comment: no, I started my project now and I did'nt write any code

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the support libraries you're using, the minimum SDK version for all support library packages is at least API level 14. [link](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/packages)

The distribution of Android API level less than 10 is below 0.1%, I would recommend you to have a higher min API.[android version distributions](https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards)

Comment: I can't change my min sdk. what should I use instead of them?

Comment: this is the same question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45253882/app-compat-version-for-min-sdk-9

Comment: as there says there is no way to write android application compatible with api 9?

Comment: No, they say the last version of the support library that supports Android version 9 is 25.4.0 ..